# How to fix Avoid AlphaImageLoader filter?

Tags: css, optimization, gtmetrix

I try to increase speed of my website and I use gtmetrix for fix speed problems.

I get a message that

> Avoid AlphaImageLoader filter
>
> There is a total of 2 filters
>
> https://www.travelenter.com/bundles/bootstrapCss?v=EXugHAHZ_FGhi2mjw1qnjtce7yGY8egZz7H9mEwgBxM1

I try to fix this problem and found that if we use `filter: alpha(opacity=0);` for set opacity of **png** image , this Makes that load of web page stop until load this image and then continue .I delete all css code such as `filter: alpha(opacity=0);` of my css files and retest but don't solved .

How to fix this?

gtmetrix link: 
https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.travelenter.com/O0zZGkzL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used number code such as

`-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";` in my css file **for png image** that after delete this codes my problem solved.